# Export clearcase/quest list of users

Tags: list, export, clearcase, clearquest

Is there a way to export the list of clearcase/quest users?

I saw the utility in the "user administration" program but it export everything and I only need the users that use clearcase/quest for the last year.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that such an export should differ between ClearCase and ClearQuest, since only the latter has a user database (while the former -- ClearCase -- [relies on system account](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_access_usr_grp.htm)).

You can check, for Clearquest:

- "[Using the ClearQuest API to access a user database](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.api.tut.doc/topics/cqapi_overview_crs.htm)"
- "[Querying Rational ClearQuest user databases](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_u_mng_cqudb_qry.htm)"

ClearCase users are usually registered in a Windows group dedicated for that application (like "`ClearCaseUsers`").

So you could try and list all the users of that group (or any group you configured ClearCase to use) in order to get the list of ClearCase users.

Comment: Sorry,maybe because of my bad english im not being clear. I need the clearcase users (last users,like one year) I tought to export that info from the license but that is not possible since flex registry is registered only 16 licences (I dont know why). About what you say for the clarcase user group its fine but where I should find that info in the servers?

Comment: @user3257666 that would be for the Windows Admins to give you that list (provided your ClearCase admin give them the name of the group used to register all ClearCase users). If you know that group name and have enough right, you can try http://serverfault.com/q/49405/783.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of list are you looking for?

You can use ClearQuest OSLC CM REST API found here (https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/RcmRestCmApi) to issue an http request and get a XML list of all ClearQuest users:

```
http://localhost:8080/oslc/cqrest/repo/7.0.0/db/SAMPL/record/?oslc_cm.query=&rcm.type=users
```

Where:

```
http://localhost:8080/oslc/cqrest/repo/7.0.0/db/SAMPL/record/
```

is a sample base URL. You would have to figure out what your base URL is. The following API documentation helped me figure that out https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/CqOslcV2

You just submit that request through your browser (not IE) or in code and get back an xml response with the list of users.